# Fancybox showing on click

Tags: fancybox

i recently got a job offer and the site i'm working on uses fancybox but when i click on the photo gallery nothing shows up. The url shown the redirection but nothing is happening. The site is caprice.gr.

```
@RenderBody()

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>        !window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/scripts/libs/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>        !window.jQuery.ui && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="/scripts/libs/jquery-ui.min.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
<script src="/scripts/libs/jquery.fancybox.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.mousewheel.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.easing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery-extend.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.ba-hashchange.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/scripts/libs/mediaplayer-5.10/jwplayer.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        /*$(window).load(function () {
            if (typeof (FB) != 'undefined' && FB != null) {
                FB.XFBML.parse($('#facebook-comments').get(0));
            }
        });*/
        $(function(){
            $(document).on('contextmenu','img, .fancybox-nav', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Copyright © 2012 Caprice of Mykonos.');
            }).on('dragstart','img', function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
</script>

@RenderSection("pageJS",False)

<script>
    var _gaq = _gaq||[];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35657817-1']);
    if (location.hash == '') {
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    }
    (function (d, t) {
        var g = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0]; g.async = 1;
        g.src = ('https:' == location.protocol ? '//ssl' : '//www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s)
    } (document, 'script'));
</script>
```

Comment: Please add more details and some code. In this form, no one can answer your question.

Comment: i'm sorry this is my first time here... i posted my code from layout.vbhtml